RabbitMQ - El Worker se queda como zombie
Algo sucede entre la conexion del programa que ejecuto y RabbitMQ, porque el microservicio se queda ESPERANDO informacion y como que hay se queda como zombie, y a pesar que la cola Recibe informacion esta no es obtenida ya por el microservicio.
En un principio que levanto el programa, este se conecta y recibe informacion de la cola sin problemas pero despues de un tiempo (tiempo que aun estoy por medir), detecto que el programa ya no lee la cola o almenos esa sensacion me da porque NO VEO mensajes de error en pantalla, simplemente esta "en espera". Pero por otro lado, la COLA en rabbit-manager si tiene informacion, pero no veo que el programa la reciba.
Aqui un ejemplo de como hago esa conexion al servicio de rabbitmq, y que funciona en un principio, pero despues de cierto tiempo (el cual aun no mido), el microservicio se queda como zombie:
<?php
class worketJob {
    public function onCallback( $msg ) {
        if( !$msg->body_size ) {
            $this->onError();
        }
        else {
            echo "\n\n[INFO] ". date("Y-m-d, H:i"). " - Mensaje: ";
            echo "\n--------------------------------- Start Mensaje";
            echo "\n". $msg->body;
            echo "\n--------------------------------- Fin Mensaje";

            /* Tarea a realizar */
            /* en esta parte hago cosas con la informacion de la cola y la variable $estado cambia de 0 a 1*/

            $estado=0;

            if( !$estado ) {
                echo "\n[FAIL] ". date("Y-m-d, H:i"). " - Tarea fallo...";
                $msg->nack(); // no ack
            }
            else {
                echo "\n[EXITO] ". date("Y-m-d, H:i"). " - Tarea realizada...";
                $msg->ack(); // mandamos finalizacion
            }

            echo "\n[Done] ". date("Y-m-d, H:i"). " - Tarea terminada..."; // mensaje exito
            sleep(5); // espero 5 segundos
        }
    }

    public function onError() {
        echo "\n[WARNING] ". date("Y-m-d, H:i"). " - No se encontraron datos...";
    }
}

$obj= new worketJob(); // clase
$queue= 'nomreDeLaCola';
$a= new AMQPStreamConnection("ip_server_rabbit", RABBIT_PORT, RABBIT_USUARIO, RABBIT_PASSWORD);
$socket= $a;
$canal= $a->channel();

$canal->queue_declare(
    $queue, 
    false, 
    false, 
    false, 
    false 
);

$canal->basic_consume(
    $queue, 
    '', 
    false, 
    false, 
    false, 
    false, 
    array($obj,"onCallback") 
);

try {
    $canal->consume();
} catch (\Throwable $exception) {
    echo "\n\n===> ". $exception->getMessage();
?>

Y en la terminal veo:

[INFO] 2024-04-11, 09:00  - Mensaje:
--------------------------------- Start Mensaje {json_que_manda_la_cola}
--------------------------------- Fin Mensaje
[EXITO] 2024-04-11, 09:01 - Tarea realizada... [Done] 2024-04-11,
09:02 - Tarea terminada...
[INFO] 2024-04-11, 09:00  - Mensaje:
--------------------------------- Start Mensaje {json_que_manda_la_cola}
--------------------------------- Fin Mensaje
[EXITO] 2024-04-11, 09:01 - Tarea realizada... [Done] 2024-04-11,
09:02 - Tarea terminada...

Y finalmente, ya no veo que siga recibiendo trabajo de la cola, pero tampoco veo un mensaje de error de que el script haya frenado... solo me toca detener el script y volver a levantarlo. Y ahora si, continua recibiendo y procesando el trabajo de la cola.
